# Is there any biological support for the concept of "chakras"?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology

**Is there any support in modern biology for the [ancient concept of "Chakras"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra)?**

I've seen the concept of 7 chakras [linked to the major endocrine glands in the human body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra#Endocrine_system) (pineal,thyroid, adrenal, testes, etc). This makes some sense, however, I've seen other numbering start to talk about 14, 21, etc number of chakras, which makes me skeptical.  Are chakras real?

Comment: I think the question should be migrated to skeptics.SE. In the same time, it will be very important to very accurately defined what is meant by "support for the concept of chakra". Does it mean "Is it true that there is more energy flowing at key points on our body" or does it mean "does medicine such as <insert some alternative medical practice> effective?". Does it means something else?

Comment: If you agree, I think you can flag your own question to ask for migration. Again, I think (might be wrong) that the question will need some remodelling to make sense of "support for the concept of chakra".

Comment: I think no matter what definition of chakra you use, it's not suitable for a science based site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question would be better suited on [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com). Also I would suggest to clearly define what you would call a "support for the concept of chakras".

Comment: @canadianer I'm afraid I must disagree with you there. The chakra is, like many things, a guess, a "theory" if you will, developed through someone's observations to explain a concept that they do not understand. This is human nature, to wonder about something and attempt to explain it. Is this not science? Wonder is at the very heart of science and an attempt to explain an observation comes soon after.

Comment: Whether this theory is right or not is obviously arguable (not only for this theory, but for many, many others as well), however I do not think it should be closed. I think it would most likely fit in a little better over in Skeptics SE. though.

Comment: @CDB If you think it belongs at skeptics SE, then it sounds like you actually agree with me ;)

Comment: @cdb a guess is not a theory.

Comment: @canadianer It definitely belongs on a science based website, otherwise you would get some pretty scientifically unsound answers. I just don't think this should be it. Than again, this is a website specifically created to answer questions regarding biology, so perhaps it should be answered here?

Comment: @dustin Good point, I should have said hypothesis. My apologies.

Comment: As is the question is fit for neither sites. You need to define better, not just by referencing to an other page, what is the concept of chakras you reference to. Then if you can formulate a "common claim" Skeptics is a good place to ask if this claim is right (see the closest to a guideline for skeptics at http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2512 ) otherwise you can move it to the beta Health site  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health but I think here is not a bad place to ask.